# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). access firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have migrated data from an app to another on Cloud Firestore, but the new deployment on the new app can't access the data on it.

I checked the config object and all the properties refer to the new app on Firebase.

Is the missing thing a kind of a link/glue between the running web app and Firestore?

Comment: if the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [ErrorCode list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode) (HTTP error code = 404), the App instance was unregistered from FCM. This usually means that the token used is no longer valid and a new one must be used.

This error can be caused by missing registration tokens, or unregistered tokens.

**Missing Registration:** If the message's target is a token value, check that the request contains a registration token.

**Not registered:** An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios, including:

- If the client app unregisters with FCM.
- If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
- If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS devices).
- If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
  For all these cases, remove this registration token from the app server and stop using it to send messages.

Comment: @Yusuf was this answer useful?